# Get hrefs from <a> Tags Located in the Divs with a Specific Classes Using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I need to get hrefs from `<a>` tags in a website, but not all, but only ones that are in the spans locted in the `<div>`s with classes `arm`

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="arm">
      <span>
        <a href="1">link</a>
        <a href="2">link</a>
        <a href="3">link</a>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="arm">
      <span>
        <a href="4">link</a>
        <a href="5">link</a>
        <a href="6">link</a>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="arm">
      <span>
        <a href="7">link</a>
        <a href="8">link</a>
        <a href="9">link</a>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="footnote">
      <span>
        <a href="1">anotherLink</a>
        <a href="2">anotherLink</a>
        <a href="3">anotherLink</a>
      </span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

request = requests.get("url")
html = bs(request.content, 'html.parser')

for arm in html.select(".arm"):
    anchor = arm.select("span > a")
    print("anchor['href']")
```

But my code doesn't print anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine until you get to the `print("anchor['href']")` line which I assume is meant to be `print(anchor['href'])`.

Now, anchor is a ResultSet, which means you will need another loop to get the hrefs. Here is how those final lines should look like if you want minimum modification to your code:

```py
for arm in soup.select(".arm"):
    anchor = arm.select("span > a")
    for x in anchor:
        print(x.attrs['href'])
```

We basically add:

```
    for x in anchor:
        print(x.attrs['href'])
```

And you should get the hrefs. All the best.

This is my output:
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately...
https://imgur.com/n9t4FDN

Comment: Based on the html you gave above, on my end everything outputs perfectly. 

Would you mind running a `print(len(anchor))` before the `for x in anchor:` line and comment what answer it gives you. Should be giving you 3 for each arm class.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a pic of what my output looks like with the html you posted

Comment: Again no output and no errors, but html is not mine, I'm parsing another website

Comment: Hmmm...when you run `print(response.content)`, does it come out blank ?

And if does give you content, please confirm if it actually has the `arm` class in it. If it does have even a single `arm` class, then `print(len(anchor))` should not be giving you a blank line.

Comment: NameError: name 'response' is not defined

Comment: Ah, sorry. Based on your snippet, it should be `print(request.content)`

Comment: Well, yes, here is the problem...
b'<head><title>Not Acceptable!</title></head><body><h1>Not Acceptable!</h1><p>An appropriate representation of the requested resource could not be found on this server. This error was generated by Mod_Security.</p></body></html>'

Comment: Seems you are not getting a valid response. Once you do, the solution above should work perfectly. Once confirmed, feel free to upvote for clarity of whoever has such a problem in future.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `find.all()` method to obtain the values in a specific `tags` and `class`

I have replicated your HTML file and obtain the values in the `span` tag. Please see my sample code below.

### Replicated HTML file:

```
# Creating the HTML file
file_html = open("demo.html", "w")
# Adding the input data to the HTML file
file_html.write('''<html>
  <body>
    <div class="arm">
      <span>
        <a href="1">link</a>
        <a href="2">link</a>
        <a href="3">link</a>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="arm">
      <span>
        <a href="4">link</a>
        <a href="5">link</a>
        <a href="6">link</a>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="arm">
      <span>
        <a href="7">link</a>
        <a href="8">link</a>
        <a href="9">link</a>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="footnote">
      <span>
        <a href="1">anotherLink</a>
        <a href="2">anotherLink</a>
        <a href="3">anotherLink</a>
      </span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>''')
# Saving the data into the HTML file
file_html.close()
```

### code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

#reading the replicated html file
demo = open("demo.html", "r")
results = bs(demo, 'html.parser')

#Using find.all method to find specific tags and class
job_elements = results.find_all("div", class_="arm")

for job_element in job_elements:
    links = job_element.find_all("a")
    for link in links:
        print(link['href'])
```

### Output:

[image]

### reference:

https://realpython.com/beautiful-soup-web-scraper-python/

Comment: I needed tags hrefs, not their contents

Comment: My bad, I've already updated my answer to obtain tags href @Davitpetrosyan